# css being overridden/shut off

Tags: css

I downloaded a website template and I am trying to add [an iChat](http://www.rwe-uk.com/static/ichat_with_css3/speech_bubbles.html) like message system using CSS as seen in the link (style 4). My problem is if I take out the template I can see the bubbles as shown in the iChat example. You can see my page [here](http://niftybytes.com/fbportal/feedback.php) of what I get while using the template.

My question is why is the CSS being shut off/overridden for the bubbles while the template is on.

Comment: If you use Chrome or Firefox's developer tools, the CSS inspector will tell you exactly which rules apply to any element, which file they came from, and which have been overridden by other styles.

Comment: I see only a login screen when visiting your page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need a doctype on the top of the page probably.

```
   <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
```